# UIActionsheet with UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I have placed UIDatePicker into UIActionSheet. In Landscape mode when click the down arrow button (image 1) the Actionsheet appears but the Set Date field is hidden. Will Apple reject my app for this behaviour?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: If I minimize the height of Actionsheet , then the Date picker crops.That is full view of Picker is not visible.

Comment: No, apple cannot reject your app for this reason but this will not look good from the user view point.